# Image source late binding - get rid of redundant error icon displayed in the meantime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

On the page I have img declaration:

```
<img src="" alt="" itemid="7" />
```

I want to bind this image with appropriate source url. This url I need to fetch from external service:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = $(img).attr('itemid');
    getImageUrl(id);  // fetch the image source url, takes about 5 seconds
});

function getImageUrl(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://images.service.svc/get?id=' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success:
            /* after about 5 seconds */
            function (result) {
                var imageUrl = result.ImageUrl;
                image.attr('src', imageUrl);
            }
    });
}
```

Meantime, in IE I get error image

[image]

How to show the image after source url is binded to image, next it is downloaded by the browser and finally ready to display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the image to `visibility:hidden` in the CSS, then in your JavaScript, after the attribute is finished, set the CSS to `visibility:visible`

```
image.css('visibility','visible');
```